# AppleScript to Open New Tab in Terminal no longer working in Mountain Lion?

Tags: applescript, osx-mountain-lion

I used to run the following code in Lion to open terminal, update a project, then open a new tab, and run again to update a second, third, and fourth. Since the Mountain Lion upgrade, this no longer works. Half the time it seems to open Finder at my home directory, and the other half it seems to open the OSX font / text dialog. I've confirmed that Cmd+T should still open a new tab. Any idea why it broke?

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate

tell application "Terminal"

    do script "cd Projects/blahblah/trunk" in front window
    do script "svn up" in front window

end tell

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out I needed to tell Terminal to activate between each call for some reason. Lion never made me do that.

```
tell application "Terminal" to activate

tell application "Terminal"

    delay 0.25

    do script "cd Projects/firstone/trunk && svn up" in front window
end tell

tell application "Terminal" to activate

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down

tell application "Terminal"

    delay 0.25

    do script "cd Projects/secondone/trunk && svn up" in front window

end tell
```

Comment: From here (http://superuser.com/questions/466619/open-new-terminal-tab-and-execute-script) it seems it's something along the lines of `tell application "Terminal" to activate`

Comment: `tell application "Terminal" to activate

tell application "Terminal"
 
 delay 0.25
 do script "cd Projects/firstone/trunk && svn up" in front window
 
end tell

tell application "Terminal" to activate

tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down

tell application "Terminal"
 
 delay 0.25
 do script "cd Projects/secondone/trunk && svn up" in front window
 
end tell`